# How to translate small bash code to csh / tcsh (setting GNOME terminal title)

Tags: bash, translate, csh, tcsh, gnome-terminal

I need help to translate the following `bash` code to `tcsh` :

```
case $TERM in
    (xterm*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}\007"'
    ;;
esac
```

It is part of my `.bashrc` on all the machines which have `bash` as login shell. The code sets the GNOME terminal title to `user@somehost` (obviously with the real user name and host name). However some hosts have `tcsh` as login shell, so I need to translate the code into `tcsh` and add it to the `.tcshrc` .

I considered to somehow `source` another file with the `bash` code from inside the `.tcshrc` file, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add the sequence to your `prompt` string or use `precmd`.

```
set prompt = "%{\033]0;%n@%M\007%}$prompt"
```

or

```
alias precmd 'echo -n "\033]0;$user@`hostname`\007"'
```

The conditional assignment:

```
switch ($term)
    case xterm*:
        set prompt = "%{\033]0;%n@%M\007%}$prompt"  # or the alias command
    breaksw
endsw
```